# Why by choosing a Node in the Tree view ,Cursor goes to the first record in the tables(Binding Tree View to win controls does not work properly)?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hi there on site members,
I need a little help , I have used this code to  populate a Tree view from three tables With existing table links:

```vb
Private Sub FillTREEVIEWTEXT()
    Dim connGlobe As New SqlConnection("Data Source=ACCOUNTING\ACCOUNTING;Initial Catalog=DELLY;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    Dim pkp(0), pke(0) As DataColumn
    Dim dtgroup, dtkol, dtmoin As New DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    'filling the datatables
    Try
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT stgrcode ,cast(stgrcode as varchar) +' / '+ cast(STGRNAME as varchar) as STGRNAME FROM tfw_accgrfixcode ORDER BY STGRCODE", connGlobe)
        dtgroup.Clear()
        da.Fill(dtgroup)
        pke(0) = dtgroup.Columns("STGRCODE")
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT stgrcode,stkolcode ,cast(stkolcode as varchar) +' / '+ cast(STKOLNAME as varchar) as STKOLNAME FROM tfw_acckolfixcode", connGlobe)
        dtkol.Clear()
        da.Fill(dtkol)
        pke(0) = dtkol.Columns("STGRCODE")
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select stgrcode,ukolcode ,cast(acckind as varchar) +' / '+ cast(UMOINNAME as varchar) as UMOINNAME from TFW_ACCMOFIXCODE", connGlobe)
        dtmoin.Clear()
        da.Fill(dtmoin)
        pke(0) = dtmoin.Columns("STGRCODE")
        connGlobe.Open()
        'Creating the treeview
        Dim tempNode As TreeNode

        For i = 0 To dtgroup.Rows.Count - 1
            TREEVIEW1.Nodes.Add(dtgroup.Rows(i).Item("STGRNAME"))
            For j = 0 To dtkol.Rows.Count - 1
                If dtgroup.Rows(i).Item("STGRCODE") = dtkol.Rows(j).Item("STGRCODE") Then
                    tempNode = TREEVIEW1.Nodes(i).Nodes.Add(dtkol.Rows(j).Item("STKOLNAME"))
                    For k = 0 To dtmoin.Rows.Count - 1
                        If dtkol.Rows(j).Item("STkolCODE") = dtmoin.Rows(k).Item("ukolCODE") Then
                            tempNode.Nodes.Add(dtmoin.Rows(k).Item("UMOINNAME"))
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        Next
        connGlobe.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

So far the app works well, But now I need to select Node to update the table via Tree View , I do not know why by selecting any of the parent, child or grandchild in the text boxes the first row value of the tables is displayed, In other words, the values of the selected node in the text boxes are not displayed.

this is my code for binding win controls to tree view:

```vb
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TREEVIEW1.AfterSelect

    Dim connGlobe As New SqlConnection("Data Source=ACCOUNTING\ACCOUNTING;Initial Catalog=DELLY;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    Dim dtContinent As New DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT g.STGRCODE ,g.STGRNAME,G.ISFIX,K.ISFIX,K.MAHIAT,k.STkolCODE,k.STGRCODE,k.STKOLNAME,m.STMOINCODE,m.UMOINNAME,m.TAFKINDNAME01,m.TAFKINDNAME02,m.TAFKINDNAME03,m.TAFKINDNAME04,m.TAFKINDNAME05,m.TAFKINDNAME06,m.TAFKINDNAME07,TAFKINDNO,TAFKINDNO1,TAFKINDNO2,TAFKINDNO3,TAFKINDNO4,TAFKINDNO5,TAFKINDNO6,ISMNDTAF01,ISMNDTAF02,ISMNDTAF03,ISMNDTAF04,ISMNDTAF05,ISMNDTAF06,ISMNDTAF07 FROM tfw_accgrfixcode as g INNER JOIN tfw_acckolfixcode AS k
                   ON g.stgrcode = k.stgrcode 
                   INNER JOIN TFW_ACCMOFIXCODE AS m 
                   ON m.stgrcode = m.stgrcode", connGlobe)
        da.Fill(dtContinent)
        connGlobe.Open()
        Dim commandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dtContinent
        da.Update(DirectCast(bindingSource1.DataSource, DataTable))
        bindingSource1.Position = bindingSource1.IndexOf(e.Node.Text)

        'If e.Node.Tag.ToString = "" Then Return
        'TextBox1.Text = DirectCast(bindingSource1.Item(bindingSource1.Find("STGRNAME", e.Node.Tag)), DataRowView).Item("STGRCODE").ToString

        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "STGRCODE")
        TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "STKOLCODE")
        TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "STMOINCODE")
        TextBox4.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "STGRNAME")
        TextBox5.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "STKOLNAME")
        TextBox6.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "UMOINNAME")
        RadioButton1.DataBindings.Add("CHECKED", bindingSource1, "ISFIX")
        RadioButton2.DataBindings.Add("CHECKED", bindingSource1, "MAHIAT")
        RadioButton3.DataBindings.Add("CHECKED", bindingSource1, "ISFIX")
        RadioButton4.DataBindings.Add("CHECKED", bindingSource1, "MAHIAT")

        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME01")
        ComboBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME02")
        ComboBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME03")
        ComboBox4.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME04")
        ComboBox5.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME05")
        ComboBox6.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME06")
        ComboBox7.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNAME07")

        TextBox21.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO")
        TextBox20.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO1")
        TextBox19.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO2")
        TextBox18.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO3")
        TextBox17.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO4")
        TextBox16.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO5")
        TextBox15.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "TAFKINDNO6")

        TextBox7.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF01")
        TextBox8.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF02")
        TextBox9.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF03")
        TextBox10.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF04")
        TextBox11.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF05")
        TextBox12.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF06")
        TextBox13.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "ISMNDTAF07")

        TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox2.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox3.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox4.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox5.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox6.DataBindings.Clear()
        RadioButton1.DataBindings.Clear()
        RadioButton2.DataBindings.Clear()
        RadioButton3.DataBindings.Clear()
        RadioButton4.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox2.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox3.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox4.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox5.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox6.DataBindings.Clear()
        ComboBox7.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox21.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox20.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox19.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox18.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox17.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox16.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox15.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox7.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox8.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox9.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox10.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox11.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox12.DataBindings.Clear()
        TextBox13.DataBindings.Clear()
        connGlobe.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me? Please
I give you the best regards.